# What kind of authentication should be used for a mobile application in Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

We are currently developing a mobile application and a **RESTful API** in Laravel 5.6.

I have a question with regard to Laravel Passport, since I have seen some tutorials but I do not understand much what kind of authentication I should use for my RESTful API.

For now we are using **"Password Grant Tokens"**.

**Questions**

1. Is it correct to use "Password Grant Tokens" for the authentication of a mobile application?
2. When Laravel Passport is installed it automatically generates 2 tokens. It is correct to use only these 2 tokens for all my users of the application or I must generate a token for each user.

I hope and you can help me.

Regards